"Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin." Although newest version is set
My flutter code that I have been writing in Android Studio is building fine on iOS. However if I try to run it on an Android simulator, I get a lenghty error message that I don't understand. The last bit of it says
[!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                     │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then │
│ update /Users/valerievogt/StudioProjects/chuddyapp/android/build.gradle:                   │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'

So I went ahead and added the kotlin version to my android/build.gradle like so:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.23'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

This is my settings.gradle:
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.23" apply false
}

include ":app"

The error persists though and nothing has changed.
I tried updating and upgrading all dependencies, flutter, android sdk, studio and already replaced two packages, but I keep getting this error.
The whole error message reads like this and is way above my head:
e: /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/8e8d6d4aa01a38286ceaa1a7db4d6398/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.9.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (44, 38): Unresolved reference: ArrayList
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (45, 30): Unresolved reference: HashMap
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (63, 14): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (64, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (65, 25): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (66, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (67, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (68, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (73, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (77, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (78, 15): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (79, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (80, 25): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (81, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (87, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (87, 33): Unresolved reference: startsWith
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (88, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (90, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (91, 25): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (92, 25): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (94, 29): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (95, 25): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (99, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (104, 33): Unresolved reference: startsWith
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (105, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (105, 33): Unresolved reference: startsWith
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (106, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (107, 25): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (109, 25): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (111, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (113, 25): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (115, 25): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (117, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (119, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (120, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (125, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (130, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (132, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (133, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (135, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (140, 57): Unresolved reference: startsWith
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (142, 32): Unresolved reference: HashMap
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (147, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (153, 34): Unresolved reference: startsWith
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (154, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/username/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_tts-4.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tundralabs/fluttertts/FlutterTtsPlugin.kt: (155, 27): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2ece6433a8ec3065ee1b823ef5a57766/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class

[.........deleted some bc of character limit]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_tts:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s

┌─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                     │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then │
│ update /Users/username/StudioProjects/chuddyapp/android/build.gradle:                   │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                    │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

What steps can I take to solve this? I'm overwhelmed.


Have you tried explicitly listing kotlin as a plug-in with the version number?

Uhm no, how would I do that?

If you share all your build.gradle files from the project and the settings.gradle file it will be easier to see how you've set Kotlin up.

@SimonJacobs this is my build.gradle:
`buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.23'
}
allprojects {
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
}
}
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}`

the fact to define the right version in the settings.gradle worked fine for me to fix this error

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The solution for me was to change the /android/settings.gradle kotlin plugin to match the version I upgraded to. From your description you would need 1.9.23, so in settings.gradle change the kotlin version:
plugins {
    ... other plugins ...
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.23" apply false
}

and rebuild.
Since you already have that in your files I expect the old version is still cached. To clear that using a flutter terminal enter:
flutter clean
then
flutter pub get
to re-download your flutter packages.
In Android Studio (I'm on Hedgehog 2023.1.1 Patch 2), from the menu choose
Build >> Clean Project
then
File >> Invalidate Caches...
Then Build >> Rebuild Project to get it running again.
Hope this works for you, or whoever else ends up here.
